# How to set Provider value from class field?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using `Provider`. I have got class. And I need to set value to `Provider` from field. But I do not have access to `context` here.

```
class _DateAndTimePickerDemoState extends State<DateAndTimePickerDemo> 
{
  DateTime _fromDate = DateTime.now();
  Provider.of<AppState>(context).selected_period = date; // here
}
```

How to set Provider value from class field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `context` in two ways:

- Inside `initState` by calling `Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() {... context ...})`
- After build method has been called `Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}`

In your case, I would call `Provider.of<AppState>(context).selected_period = date;` after `build` method, because most of the functions I define inside build method anyways so I can easily access context.

Comment: After build you mean in body of `Widget build(BuildContext context) { /* here */ }`?

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov Yes

Answer (score 4):

**Option No 1**
You can use override method initState()

```
  @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
   Future.delayed(Duration.zero,(){
     Provider.of<AppState>(context).selected_period = /* your value */;
   });
 }
```

**Option No 2**
You can set value in build() method also

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     Provider.of<AppState>(context).selected_period = /* your value */;
     // your rest of code is write here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false).selected_period = /* your value */;`

You need to set `listen` to **`false`** because Provider is used outside the build method.